# Make full copy of tab from Chrome Exstension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Chrome Extension for one large site. I need to add ability to open in new tab links that really are not links. For example:
`<a href="javascript:openModalWithContacts()">`, or `<a href="#" />` with handlers on click events

I have simple idea: on click event make a FULL copy of tab, put new tab on place where was old tab, and old tab move to the end of tabs bar, and then continue executing event which will change DOM or open new page.

But meet the challenge: Chrome method `chrome.tabs.duplicate()` just open current URL in new tab, and page are loading again. But I need to copy all context.

What do you think, how I can move all tab context from one tab to another?

Comment: There's no API to clone tab context yet, it'll probably be added in the future since chromium developers want to implement real tabs suspension.

Comment: But I am looking for method to do it manually. Probably for it I need to copy all DOM and window object. But I'm not sure that it is possible and it is enough.

Comment: Well, without a specialized API there is simply no way to copy the state of JavaScript objects, classes and so on.